# I always get an error when running cgconfigparser

Tags: cgroup

Here's my /etc/cgconfig.conf:

```
group VM {
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = "5G";
    memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = "4G";
  }
}
```

Here's my /etc/cgrules.conf

```
#<user:process>                  <controllers>    <destination>
*:/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64    memory           VM
```

but when ever I run cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf,
I always get the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup, requested group parameter does not exist
```

How may I fix this?